# In WinJS how to avoid outer div event handler affects inner div event handler

Tags: event-handling, winjs

I want to set different event handlers on nested divs, and the events are both triggered 
by right-click. Both event handlers would draw different buttons on the same area.

My code would be like this:

```
<div id="a">
    <div id="b data-win-control="WinJS.UI.ListView">
        ...
    </div>
</div>
```

I addEventListener on "div a" and "listview", the problem is that while I right-click on listView elements, triggering listView's event handler first, and then a's event handler  which will override listView's effects.

How to avoid triggering a's event handler when right-click on listView?

Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you want to stop propagation of event from parent to its child then event.stopPropagation()
is the way to go... 
For more details refer https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/event.stopPropagation